# scrapy unable to make Request() callback

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to make recursive parsing script with Scrapy, but `Request()` function doesn't call callback function `suppose_to_parse()`, nor any function provided in callback value. I tried different variations but none of them work. Where to dig ?

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector



class joomler(BaseSpider):
    name = "scrapy"
    allowed_domains = ["scrapy.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://blog.scrapy.org/"]


    def parse(self, response):
        print "Working... "+response.url
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for link in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():
            if not link.startswith('http://') and not link.startswith('#'):
               url=""
               url=(self.start_urls[0]+link).replace('//','/')
               print url
               yield Request(url, callback=self.suppose_to_parse)


    def suppose_to_parse(self, response):
        print "asdasd"
        print response.url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the yield outside of the `if` statement:

```
for link in hxs.select('//a/@href').extract():
    url = link
    if not link.startswith('http://') and not link.startswith('#'):
        url = (self.start_urls[0] + link).replace('//','/')

    print url
    yield Request(url, callback=self.suppose_to_parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but i tried your code and i think that the problem is not on the Request, the generated url's seems to be broken, if you add some url's to a list and iterate thorough them and yield the Request with the callback, it works fine.