# URLs in Scrapy crawler are not yielded to the next parser

Tags: python, scrapy, yield

I came across a yielding problem, when I was trying to crawl http://www.brand-in-trend.ru. As you see below, I'm using Scrapy and defined a Basespider. The first parser works perfectly fine and returns all brands found on the start_url.

Now, when I want to yield the callback Request to the categories parser, I don't get a response nor an Error. The spider just quits.

*Spider:*

```
class brandintrend(BaseSpider):
name = "brandintrend"

allowed_domains = [ 'trend-in-brand.ru' ]

start_urls      = [ 'http://brand-in-trend.ru/brands/' ]

def parse(self, response):
    hxs         = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    brands      = hxs.select('//div[@class="brandcol"]/ul/li/a/@href').extract()

    for brand in brands:
        brand = "http://www.brand-in-trend.ru" + brand
        print brand
        # request = Request(brand, callback=self.categories)
        yield Request(brand, callback=self.categories)

def categories(self, response):
    print "Hello World"
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    print response.url
```

I tried the following already to solve this issue:

1. I tested the generated brand urls (ex. http://www.brand-in-trend.ru/brands/parker/) in Chrome (Javasript turned off) and they worked fine.
2. I put all generated brand urls in the start_url list and tried to yield those directly to the categories parser
3. I looked at this post, which unfortunately didn't solve my problem: [scrapy unable to make Request() callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578918/scrapy-unable-to-make-request-callback)

If anybody came across a similar problem I would be greatful for a solution or advise

Thanks in advance

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set:

```
allowed_domains = [ 'trend-in-brand.ru' ]
```

but, you are crawling the url from a different domain:

```
start_urls = [ 'http://brand-in-trend.ru/brands/' ]
```

See `trend-in-brand` vs `brand-in-trend`.

Comment: Now, I see it as well. This was a nail biter and yet so simple